# listview onclick android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-contacts

I am creating an app that has a contacts list inside it. Currently the list works and displays all of my contacts just the way i want it. However i need to add a click function to them. I want to call them once i press one of them. How can i do that? I already have an onListItemClick method in the same activity due to an rss reader. How can i filter it out? Take a look at my code:

```
        //Load contacts into ListView on people screen
    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
    contactstock = new ArrayList<ContactStock>();

    mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);      
    int name = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phName = mCursor.getString(name);
        String phNumber = mCursor.getString(number);
        contactstock.add(new ContactStock(phName, phNumber));
    }
    contactListView.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            contactstock));
```

ContactStock.java:

```
public class ContactStock {

    private String name;
    private String number;

    public ContactStock(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
       this.number = number;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

}
```

ContactListAdapter.java:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private final Activity activity;
private final List stocks;

public ContactListAdapter(Activity activity, List objects) {
    super(activity, R.layout.listview_detail_tab_contact_list, objects);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.stocks = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    ContactStockView sv = null;
    if (rowView == null) {
        // Get a new instance of the row layout view
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.listview_detail_tab_contact_list, null);

        // Hold the view objects in an object,
        // so they don't need to be re-fetched
        sv = new ContactStockView();
        sv.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);

        sv.number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);

        // Cache the view objects in the tag,
        // so they can be re-accessed later
        rowView.setTag(sv);
    } else {
        sv = (ContactStockView) rowView.getTag();
    }
    // Transfer the stock data from the data object
    // to the view objects
    ContactStock currentStock = (ContactStock) stocks.get(position);
    sv.name.setText(currentStock.getName());
    sv.number.setText(currentStock.getNumber());

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return rowView;
}

protected static class ContactStockView {
    protected TextView name;
    protected TextView number;
}
}
```

My current listview code(for rss viewer):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position).toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

ListView row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/defaultavatar" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Who am I"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="000000000" />

</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the phone number from the contact i tapped by using this code:

```
contactstock.get(arg2).getNumber()
```

Comment: seriously I haven't understood what you want.......explain clearly what do you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, so i have an application. Inside it i have two listviews. One for rss, and one for contacts. I have successfully loaded all of the contacts into one of the listview using an id to the listview. The other one used getListView(). The rss application needs a method for opening a subject once you tap it. The onListItemClick() method has the responsebility for that action. I need to add a click function to my contacts screen, but since i already use the onListItemClick() method, i need that method to call a contact once i click it, and dont get confused with the rss reader

Comment: so you want to handle both listview's onclick in onListItemClick method right......Then in the onListItemClick method first parameter is listview check if listview id is contacts one or not if contacts one than call the respective method something like this if(l.getId)()==R.id.yourlistid){do something}else{do something},  is it what you want

Comment: Yeah, that's what i want. However another answer here said that i could do something else. I did think about your solution. But when he reminded me of the other one, that wasn't a problem anymore. It's working now. How do i find the number of the contact i press?

Comment: I'll post the answer.....

Comment: post your custom listview xml of two textviews..I'll show you how to get the phone number

Comment: Post the listview row xml? Ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set both listviews and set onItemClickListener for each one.

```
ListView l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView l2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);

// listener for the first one 
l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

 // listener for the other
 l2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, i've implemented it, and it works. I just need a function for calling the contact i press.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you say is you are having 2 listview.
You can use setOnItemClickListener to the listview instead of using onListItemClick.

```
   contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

Comment: It should be AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()